# How to hide UV seam through texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

Could you guys please help me with this annoying problem? Is there a special way to go about fixing this marking seam problem? There's no edge crease and everything's in smooth.
I tried blending the UV edges in texture paint, but that doesn't make any difference.

[image]

edit:
I forgot to mention that it only shows with the UV normal. any of the other textures it doesn't show.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this looks like normals problem (but how to be sure ?). If this is it, go to edit mode, select all and "ctrl + N".  But surely sharing the blend file (you can do it in that site http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) can help to understand what is wrong.

Comment: thank you lemon for your comment. I would upload the whole thing, but it has so many textures and sculpted models. It's not a normal problem. The only reason why the color is messed up is because the normal map strength is beyond 1.5. The problem I'm faced is just the mark seam line showing through texture.

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured it out with much googling. I even redid the mark seam and everything.

Turns out when creating a new image texture, I had to click on the checkmark that says 32 bit float and now the seam problem went away along with some sloppy normal map problems that I kept getting. I guess the extra resolution is needed.
source: https://developer.blender.org/T42056